# Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' MatTable Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, async-pipe

I am trying to use Angular MatTable with an async pipe. I get the data from RESTAPI as Observable. However, when I use ([dataSource] = "dataSource | async") in this way, I get the error I mentioned above.

repository.service.ts:

```
public GetList(controller: string): Observable<T[]> {
return this.httpclient.get<T[]>(this.apiURL + '/' + controller + '/getList', { headers: this.headers });}
```

contact.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.contactService.GetList("OfferContact").subscribe(res => {
  this.ContactList = res
  this.setFunctions(this.ContactList)
})} 
setFunctions(list) {
  this.dataSource.data = list;
  this.spinner.hide()
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

contact.component.html:

```
           <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource|async" matSort>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Firma Adı </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.company}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Yetkili Adı </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
                </ng-container> 
                   ...
                 </table>
            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[20, 30, 50, 70, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

the error

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgXCA.png) is the screenshot. As you can see at the bottom right, the data is fetched but not processed into the table.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe could only be used in conjunction with an observable. You're trying with the response from the observable instead.

#### Option 1: without `async` pipe

You could simply simply remove the `async` pipe. This might throw an error in the console at component initialization when the `dataSource` variable is `undefined`.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Firma Adı </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.company}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Yetkili Adı </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container> 
        ...
</table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[20, 30, 50, 70, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

#### Option 2: with `async` pipe

You could assign the HTTP request to a variable in the controller. You could then use `map` operator to set `data`, `paginator` and `sort` properties and `finalize` operator to hide the spinner.

Try the following

Controller

```js
dataSource$: Observable<any>;  // <-- define it as an observable ('$' at end is convention)
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource$ = this.contactService.GetList("OfferContact").pipe(
    tap(res => {
      this.ContactList = res   // <-- is `this.ContactList` even required?
    }),
    map(dataSource => ({
      ...dataSource, 
      dataSource['data']: res,
      dataSource['paginator']: this.paginator,
      dataSource['sort']: this.sort
    })),
    finalize(() => this.spinner.hide())
  );
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(dataSource$ | async) as dataSource">   <!-- wrap it in *ngIf to reuse the response -->
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="company">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Firma Adı </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.company}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Yetkili Adı </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container> 
            ...
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[20, 30, 50, 70, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</ng-container>
```

Edit: Change `res` to `dataSource` inside `map` operator

Comment: Frankly, I don't know how to use the operations inside the map (...) function. For example `... dataSource,` =>
`Cannot find name 'dataSource'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.dataSource'?` gives a warning. `dataSource.data: res,` => `An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.` gives a warning. I don't know if `... dataSource` is an acronym or a usage.

Comment: That was my mistake. I assigned the response to variable `res` instead of `dataSource`. I've updated the answer. Also I've replaced dot notation with bracket notation to avoid potential `undefined` errors by TS Linter. Please try the solution again.

Comment: thank you and Akif for your effort. It didn't worked. I will use first solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete the pipe "async" like this:

```
 [dataSource]="dataSource"
```

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), you can use an async pipe with observable or promise. But in your case, your data source is not an observable or a promise itself. Your getList method is observable. So, you can't use an async pipe with your data source as you tried.

Comment: I know this usage. But when i use this, it takes 10-15 seconds to load page. So I wanted to use async pipe. It loads immediately but not data rows

Comment: I edited the answer. @Michael D has a good explanation for your requirements.